# Laravel Hash::check() using different salt and prefix

Tags: php, laravel, cryptography, bcrypt, salt

I use a different database and table for user authentication. Now I have current Hash as an example:

```
'$2a$08$UU.AJY.bcf0uJAp12WZvy.XE6CCgNAmuX8Hr17Pfkh3FRyFHWhBtO' = Test12345
```

But when I use `Hash::check('Test12345', '$2a$08$UU.AJY.bcf0uJAp12WZvy.XE6CCgNAmuX8Hr17Pfkh3FRyFHWhBtO')` it always returns false. So I think that's because the hashing uses a different method, so the prefix is $2a instead of $2y and 8 rounds instead of 12. I already tried to use `$2y$12$UU.AJY.bcf0uJAp12WZvy.XE6CCgNAmuX8Hr17Pfkh3FRyFHWhBtO` as my Hash to check, that doesn't work aswell and I just saw that on another stackoverflow post so I gave it a try.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you hash those passwords originally?

Comment: I didn't hash them, it's from a thrid party application. https://github.com/WoltLab/WCF/blob/master/wcfsetup/install/files/lib/util/PasswordUtil.class.php#L169 That's the file where the password gets generated.

Comment: you mean you ran it through `Hash::check` not `Auth::check` right?

Comment: @lagbox yeah thanks I changed it, but in the title it was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally found it out. I first have to get the salt from the hash and hash the password once, then verify it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

the same value can be hashed in different "codes"

to login use:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {

            return "login sucess";
        }
        else{
       
            return "fail";
        }
```

Comment: I already tried that and it doesn't work because the password doesn't get checked correctly.

Comment: insert the password on database using $password=bcrypt("test");  use the bcrypt(); to encrypt

Comment: I don't save the passwords, I just check them.the encryption method is from another application.

Comment: can you explain a little more in detail what you are trying to do for sure?

Comment: So I have one database used by a forum software. There is a registration module where users can create an account. That account get stored into "database1", then I have another Database ("database2") for my Laravel application, now I want to use the other database so user can login with the same credentials. The problem is, the forum saves those passwords with a double salted hash and I can't get the check working in Laravel.

Comment: so the password in database1 dont are generate with laravel?... and the goal is verify with the laravel if the "test123" is equal hash on database1